# Corda transfer of Linear State, collecting signatures

Tags: corda

I've implemented several commands, where the notary signature fulfils the use case. There are 2 cases though where I have open questions:

- I have an owner field that changes from input/output state, all fine, but I want the new owner to sign off on it, e.g. I need a mechanism to retrieve the state via the vault (last unconsumed?), I guess I need to authenticate and filter on the participants and make the new owner sign it, e.g. "press a button", how would I do that?
- How do I finalize a linear state, e.g. that it cannot take part in any form of transaction/command thereafter?

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class DeviceFlow(private val deviceState: DeviceState,
                 private val stateAndRef: Optional<StateAndRef<DeviceState>>,
                 private val command: DeviceContract.Commands)
    : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    override val progressTracker = tracker()

    companion object {
        object GENERATING_TRANSACTION : Step("Generating transaction based on new IOU.")
        object VERIFYING_TRANSACTION : Step("Verifying contract constraints.")
        object SIGNING_TRANSACTION : Step("Signing transaction with our private key.")
        object GATHERING_SIGS : Step("Gathering the counterparty's signature.") {
            override fun childProgressTracker() = CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()
        }

        object FINALISING_TRANSACTION : Step("Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.") {
            override fun childProgressTracker() = FinalityFlow.tracker()
        }

        fun tracker() = ProgressTracker(
                GENERATING_TRANSACTION,
                VERIFYING_TRANSACTION,
                SIGNING_TRANSACTION,
                GATHERING_SIGS,
                FINALISING_TRANSACTION
        )
    }

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        progressTracker.currentStep = GENERATING_TRANSACTION
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getNotary(CordaX500Name("Notary", "London", "GB"))
        val transactionBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
                .addCommand(command, deviceState.participants.map { it.owningKey })
                .addOutputState(deviceState, DeviceContract.ID)
        if (stateAndRef.isPresent)
            transactionBuilder.addInputState(stateAndRef.get())
        progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_TRANSACTION
        transactionBuilder.verify(serviceHub)
        progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING_TRANSACTION
        val signedTransaction = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilder)
        val otherPartySession = initiateFlow(notary!!)
        val fullySignedTx = subFlow(
                CollectSignaturesFlow(signedTransaction, setOf(otherPartySession), GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))
        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION
        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, setOf(otherPartySession), FINALISING_TRANSACTION.childProgressTracker()))
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(DeviceFlow::class)
class DeviceCreateFlowResponder(val flowSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(flowSession) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
                val output = stx.tx.outputs.single().data
                "This must be a Device transaction." using (output is DeviceState)
            }
        }
        val txId = subFlow(signTransactionFlow).id
        return subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(flowSession, expectedTxId = txId))
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just want the state and that guy no need to sign u have 2 way
first one add him to participant and don't put his signature into the command when you create transaction, second way use broadcast flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New owner sign off**

- You would retrieve the latest version of the state from the vault. The latest version should be unconsumed.
- Create a TransactionBuilder and add this state as input.
- Create a replica of this state, but change the owner property to reflect the new owner. Add this as an output to the TransactionBuilder.
- Ensure your contract rules governing the state enforce that the previous owner and new owner are both required signers.

**Finalising a linear (or any state)**

- You could add a property to the state and have your contract enforce that the state can no longer evolve once this property has been set.
- You can consume the state by adding it to a transaction as an input and not adding an output. (Again, your contact would have to allow this)